# Get all users that are followed a particular Twitter user

Tags: python, api, twitter

I would like to get a list of all users a particular user is following. (Using a Python wrapper).

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964772/get-users-a-twitter-user-is-following) one. But how do I do the same in Python ?

Comment: What have you tried already? There are several Python libraries available, which one are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your goal can be achieved using the [Tweepy](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html) library for Python

## step 1

Create a twitter developer account [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en)

## step 2

Install the tweepy library instructions available [here](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/install.html)

## Example

```
# import tweepy library
import tweepy

# define your developer keys from https://developer.twitter.com/en
consumer_key='<your consumer_key here>'
consumer_secret='<your consumer_secret here>'
access_token='<your access_token here>'
acess_token_sectret='<your acess_token_sectret here>'

# use those defined keys to login to twitter using tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# use tweepy to search for all the accounts that StackOverflow is following (to change which account it searches just change the username)
for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, screen_name="StackOverflow").items():
    # Print the username of each user who is following the account
    print('following: ' + user.screen_name)
```

## Note

Twitters rate limits for getting the followers of accounts is quite strict. You may need to wait a period of time between searches.